# Dimple Time Format Juggling

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I am very confused by the way dates are handled by dimple (or maybe it is just D3).

My problem can be divided in two questions:

1. My dates come as a column in my csv file in the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. In order to convert them to date objects, I currently use the same loop I used to have in "vanilla" d3.

   ```
   data.forEach(function (d) {
      var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
      d.Date = format.parse(d.Date);
   });
   ```

   Is there a quicker way to do this with? Maybe with the [timeField function](http://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#wiki-timeField)? Or [dateParseFormat](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#wiki-dateParseFormat)? I might be wrong but those functions looks like helpers to handle dates.
2. The main reason why I want to control my time objects is to be able to reformat them. Documentation seems to indicate that the [tickFormat function](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#wiki-tickFormat) can be used for this. Unfortunately I also failed at using it. My best guess:

   `var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Date");`

   `x.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m")); // For example for a year-month format`

only returns

**x.tickFormat is not a function**

Thanks a lot,

Xavier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time formatting relates to time axes.  You don't need your loop if you want to use the time axis, just use:

```
myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "Date", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%Y-%m");
```

where "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" is your input and "%Y-%m" is your output format.  The reason for the "x.tickFormat is not a function" error is that it isn't :).  You can set the tickFormat used by the time axis as a property if you wish but it isn't required if you use the factory method above:

```
myTimeAxis.tickFormat = "%Y-%m";
```

But this only works with a time axis.

An example of the time axes in action can be found here:

http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_time_axis

Hope that helps

John

Comment: So, that works perfectly for line/area charts, but if I want to do a bar chart, I need to use addCategoryAxis to get a proper bar width. In that case, can I still avoid my loop? 

It seems not as easy as writing `.addCategoryAxis("x", "Date", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%B %d");` :)

Comment: I'm afraid not.  You can use the floatingBarWidth on the time axis (https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#wiki-floatingBarWidth) if you want to specify the width of bars, otherwise you need to go back to your loop and use a category axis.

Comment: Thanks, floatingBarWidth will make the bars overflow on the extreme right and extreme left. So back to the loop I guess!

Comment: yes, you can use OverrideMin and OverrideMax to manually set the bounds but I'd probably use the loop if I were you.