# Change format and data of datetime X-axis in a line chart with d3 Javascript library

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I have to create a Line chart using D3 and dimple library with JavaScript. The Y-axis represent the measure of a pyranometer (Example: 530) and the X-axis represent the instant of time of this measure (last 24hours). (Example: Tue Dec 31 17:40:00 CET 2013)
This chart is a dinamic chart. I take the data of a database and I refresh the chart every 5 minut.

I have this problem: There are so many data in the X-axis and i can't watch nothing in the x-axis. This is a picture of my chart:

[image]

I need to reorganize the data of X-axis. I only have to put a tick every 4 hour. The x-axis have to be like this:

[image]

So, I have to change the format of the X-axis and only put a tick every 4 hours of the last 24 hours. Moreover, I have to put the day below.

Do you have any idea of How could I do this?

This is the code of my chart:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#container", 500, 500);
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data2);
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "time");
x.addOrderRule(Date);
var y1 = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Piranometro");
var piranometro = myChart.addSeries("Piranom.", dimple.plot.line,[x,y1]);               
myChart.draw();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
myChart.addTimeAxis()
```

instead of

```
myChart.addCategoryAxis()
```

Here is an advanced time axis example (both x and y are time axis):

[Advanced Time Axis Sample](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_time_axis)

Documentation on addTimeAxis():

[Dimple  addTimeAxis() function](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#wiki-addTimeAxis)

Related question:

[Dimple Time Format Juggling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195870/dimple-time-format-juggling)

For displaying days below the hour axis, you can utilize second time axis.

Hope all this will help you find solution that fits your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. 

If I use:

    myChart.addTimeAxis("x","time")
instead of

    myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "time")

the line isn't displayed. 
I think I have to describe my data. It's like this:

    data = [{"time":"1.4543443", "Piranometro":"100.0","x":"Piranómetro"},...]
             
I don't know the reason why the line isn't displayed with a a TimeAxis. 
I am researching with the examples but I can't get the solution.

Comment: addTimeAxis() has four arguments: position, timeField, inputFormat, outputFormat

Comment: You may need some conversion related to field "time". Check what you really have in that field, and devise proper conversion so that code can understand the data.

Comment: Sorry,there was a mistake. Data is like this: data = [{"time":"Thu Jan 02 12:28:00 CET 2014", "Piranometro":"100.0","x":"Piranómetro"},...]

Comment: I tried of this way: data.forEach(function (d) { d["hour"] = d["time"].substring(0, d["time"].length - 8); }, this);var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "hour","%a %b %d %H:%M:%S","%H");x.addOrderRule(Date);x.timePeriod = d3.time.hours;x.timeInterval = 3; But the line isn't display

Comment: addTimeAxis() shouldt be called within forEach() loop, but only once. If you expect a complete answer, you should post a complete question, with all relevant data. The concept of this site is Q&A, not interactive chat.

Comment: As I said, if you want interactive help, this site is not for this. And if you are not able to post clear complete question, it is impossible that you get the solution to your problem here. I see now your another question, it even more terrible than this one.

Comment: I already use addTimeAxis(...) only once, after of forEach() loop. I only would like to have a clue about how  get the chart. I'm trying and testing a lot of things and during a lot of time, and if I am asking, it's because I can't see the way i can get the goal.

Comment: You shouldn't blindly test whatever comes to your mind, but you should first read documentation, study relevant examples, device the solution, and that if it doesn't work, post question here but with complete not working solution. And, you should try to read guidelines for questions on this site, and try to follow them. I am out of this discussion.